# How to find any function that satisfies $f(x) - f(1-x) = g(x) \text { and } f(1-x) - f(x) = g(1-x)$

Tags: functions

We are given some function $g(x), \text{ such that } g(x) + g(1-x) = 0$, for example $g(x) = (2x-1)^3$. How to find any function $f$ that satisfies the given equations below: $$f(x) - f(1-x) = g(x) \\ f(1-x) - f(x) = g(1-x)$$

I tried adding those two equations but then everything cancels and we can't find any function.

Comment: Your two conditions are just one and the same. Just replace $x$ by $1-x$.

Comment: It's a good idea to specify the domain of each function when formulating such a problem.  My guess is you want the domain to be the whole real line $\mathbb R$, but it's worth stating explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

*I am guessing that $g$ is, and $f$ shall be, a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, i.e., defined on $\Bbb R$ and with values in $\Bbb R$.*

Note that $g(\frac12)=0$. Let $h\colon[\frac12,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ be any function and define
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}h(x)&x\ge\frac12\\
h(1-x)+g(x)&x<\frac12\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ satisfies the condition(s).

**Example:** If $g(x)(2x-1)^3$, we can pick $h(x)=\sin x\cdot\sqrt{x-\frac12}$ and then obtain
$$  f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin x\cdot\sqrt{x-\frac12}&x\ge\frac12\\
\sin(1-x)\cdot\sqrt{\frac12-x}+(2x-1)^3&x<\frac12\end{cases}$$
Some special choices for $h$ *may* lead to an expression for $f$ that has a simpler appearance. For example, with the same $g$ and with $h(x)=\frac12(2x-1)^3+\sqrt{x-\frac12}$ instead of the above, we would arrive at
$$ f(x)=\frac 12(2x-1)^3+\sqrt{\left|x-\frac12\right|}.$$